# Безопасны ли эти команды DISM для Windows и для ее резервных образов?

Tags: windows, cmd, ос

Здравствуйте. У меня Windows 8.1.

Решил на всякий случай проверить резервный образ системы, в хорошем ли он состоянии, потому что провожу полную уборку на компьютере, и лучше сейчас помучаться, чем потом размышлять.

Сначала проверил все системные файлы это командой:

> sfc /scannow

она сказала, что система в порядке.

А вот следующие две строки немного пугают (хотя бы из-за слова **Cleanup-Image** внутри), непонятно чем эти две команды различаются, и что они в итоге сделают с резервным образом:

> Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
>
> Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth

Я догадываюсь, что скорее всего они делают почти одно и тоже... но это же Windows, вдруг она решит что "...вот образы старые, аж за 2014 год, а давай-ка скачаем все обновления, а давай-ка удалим все старое, загрузим весь ЦП и оперативку и же/диск, и пусть у тебя инет медленный сейчас и свои дела есть, ты ведь сам нажал такую крутую команду от имени администратора...".

Ну или классика: "В процессе сканирования в результате отказа службы ***Длинное_название_очень_важной_службы*** образ был поврежден. Ошибка номер ***#12349...325***, для восстановления образа требуется диск с оригинальной Windows... и куча нервов" (диск кстати вместе с ноутом не поставлялся).

Смею предположить, что если система за все время использования не ругалась на резервный образ, то и проверять излишне? скорее всего там все в порядке

Answer (score 1):

Да, безопасны, по крайней мере на Win 8.1 лицензии. Очень желательно, чтобы был включен интернет при использовании этих команд. Команда

> Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

также безопасна.

Comment: Проверил на деле

Comment: Было бы полезнее написать, что же эти команды делают, а то "безопасность" в данном случае понятие субъективное.